# Box.com getting Refresh Token

Tags: .net, api, box

I am trying to write an desktop application (.Net) to access and upload to Box.com.  I created an application with following setting:
     client_id: 3qc5********************
     client_secret:  zbKSV7*****************
     redirect_uri:  http://127.0.0.1
     Authentication Type:   Standard Authentication (3-legged OAuth2.0)
     Scopes: Read and write....
     Category: Platform: Windows,  web, desktop
     Api Key:   3qc5m46*************************
     Redirect url:   "left blank"

then using:
https://api.box.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3qc5m46******************=authenticated
Obtained the code: AZmq****************

in Postman I have the following:
     Url: https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token
     and added the parameters:
     grant_type:authorization_code
     client_id: ************************
     client_secret: **************************
     code: AZmq****************

But I get 400 bad request:
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "The client credentials are invalid"
}

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out that I needed to add redirect_uri to the post Parameters
and It worked